# How do i display my color filter images in sidebar filter?

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<ol class="filters_option-list color-filter">
    <?php
    $attribute1 = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color1'); //"color" is the attribute_code
    $allOptions = $attribute1->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
    foreach ($allOptions as $instance): ?>
      <?php
      $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
      $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
      ?>
      <li data-facet-option-hidden="false" class="filt-color <?php echo $value;?>"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <?endforeach;?>
</ol>
```

Comment: I am only getting color lables, but i want to get swatches images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color filter images means you have configureable products, filter will be automatically when you will be add configureable products. for images you have to set the swatches in color attributes. when you will be select the attributes as swatches then you will pulled out the option for upload the images. for more information , please contact with me or send me the url i will do it.

Comment: Thanks but how can i contact you? I need help very urgently..